# RedHat RPM file collision

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm

Let's assume I have two RPM packages named *1.rpm* and *2.rpm*. Both of them want to put a file *test* into */usr/bin*, but both of them use a different version of *test*. Of course I would like to have both RPMs installed on the same machine.

What would be official behavior of RedHat (let it be RHEL5) in described situation?

Comment: The first package will install fine, the second will complain that it's trying to modify a file owned by another package.  If you try to install them together, the installation should complain that a file is owned by both packages, and neither should install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming these are home-brewed RPMs, rewrite your `spec` files to install the executables under a versioned name, say `test-1.2` and `test-2.1`, and use the `update-alternatives(8)` system to configure one of them for system-wide usage.

This is the policy followed by RHEL for the `java` executables, for example.